# Mysterious WindowServer process calling every 3 seconds

Tags: macos, error

I use a program with a GUI design a little bit different than usual and a strange issue:
With all drop-down menus, something is forcing the window to close and therefore prevent me to use it.
I noticed in the console some spamming errors from the WindowServer (SkyLight) process, appearing around 20 times per minutes.

This is message I get:
"_CGXWindowIsOrderedIn: Operation on a window 0x132 requiring rights private by caller private"

I find it very strange and almost "virus-like".
I hope I'm wrong.

After scouring the web for a few hours, I can't find a way to get rid of these errors.
Is any of you have an idea of where this could come from or what can I try?

Note: It's not happening on my others user account on the same machine.

EDIT: Finally, I found the culprit!! It was an app called Witch developed by ManyTricks so nothing like a virus or a malware. I'm contacting the devs right now to see if they can fix it.

Comment: Do the errors go away if you quit your running apps? Thousands of errors in a windowed op setting up that has bugs is expected and no sign of malware. That doesn’t mean your system is good or bad, just you will want to narrow down which app is causing these errors and report / investigate that clearly.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
The errors aren't related to the application I was talking about, they start as soon as I logged in my user account and continue even if I quit the app.
However the problem of ghostly drop-down menu close made me aware of the spamming errors.
I tried using all my usual running apps in another user account to see if I could replicate the errors in the console and the drop-down menu closing without success.

Comment: Any menu bar apps or background apps?

Comment: A bunch yes! 
It was my first guess but as I said above I tried to:
1 - quit all the running apps including the background apps in my main user account (the errors were still there)
2 - on another user account (without the errors) I tried to run all the apps and background apps I use but I couldn't replicate the errors.
I don't have anymore idea of things to try to identified the culprit here…

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the culprit!! It was an app called Witch developed by ManyTricks so nothing like a virus or a malware. I'm contacting the devs right now to see if they can fix it.